# Can you save your Clojure REPL's state (or, effectivelly, can you program complex programs using REPL?)

Tags: clojure, save, read-eval-print-loop

After defining variables, functions, etc., can you save what you have done on the REPL too an text .clj file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

most people work with the repl through an editor such ad Eclipse/Emacs/vim and that editor has the ability to save the repl, though without some diligence on the developers part this will likely be an incomplete record of what happened. Some of the state of the repl may have come from loading files etc which will be in a different state.

So the short answer is typically not.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux (mine = Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS) if you are using lein then check for .lein (hidden directory) and look for repl-history. You should find the commands that you have typed or pasted into the REPL. This can be a source for later edit - I use geany...

Comment: On Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa I found the hidden file .lein-repl-history . This is to say that not all Linuxes (should that be Lini - or is that too prickly) behave the same...

Answer (score 1):

I am answering the parenthetical part of your question. For me, the Clojure REPL is very useful for testing functions and proving out concepts that take no more than a few lines. I will often put hooks in a module that is not the main, just so I can load a file and run it through a couple of functions. I can also do this from main using the same mindset; that is write a debug function.

I found the Eclipse plugin to be quite useful, but I do not use it much these days, mostly Vim and running the module with one or more special functions and running the main. I don't know of any way to save REPL state.